# Resize array into impossible shape using placeholders

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array that I am reorganizing to solve a front end issue where objects are being displayed in this order.

```
'a' 'd' 'g'
'b' 'e' 'h'
'c' 'f' 'i'
```

when they should be shown as

```
'a' 'b' 'c'
'd' 'e' 'f'
'g' 'h' 'i'
```

I solved this problem by using the following code:

```
results = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
results = np.array(results).reshape(int(len(results) / 3), 3).T.ravel().tolist()
```

The problem I now have is that when I am given an array of data whose length is not evenly divisable by 3 such as

`['a']`

I get

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (0,3)

Would the best approach be to fill it with placeholders and then remove those placeholders after the resize or is there a built in functionality in numpy to handle these types of scenerios? Also in my actual code the array is filled with objects instead of single letters so I'm not really sure what the best practice for a placeholder would be.

Comment: Numpy won't deal well with jagged arrays, you should look into padding first

Comment: `numpy.pad` might be what you want. Documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

Comment: And please add a working minimal example which we can just copy to our console. That means all input data should be given with executable code to generate the data sample.

Comment: @Scotty1- I think that is a minimal working example unless you want to include importing numpy or the documentation from the package im using on the front end to display the data

Comment: That is true. I am sorry for judging too fast. My fault.

Answer (score 2):

How about padding the size of results to nearest multiple of 3 before re-shape
You can then filter the empty values after converting back to list

```
>>> results = ['a']
>>> l = len(results)
>>> n = int(l/3)+1 if l%3 else int(l/3)
>>> np.pad(np.array(results), ((0,n*3-l)), mode='constant').reshape((n,3), order='F')
array([['a', '', '']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: This works however it still leaves the placeholders in which in my case is a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few modifications on Sunitha's answer ( I needed it to stay a 1d array and support objects as the elements) this is what I ended up with

```
l = len(results)
if(l>0):
    n = int(l/3)+1 if l%3 else int(l/3)
    results = np.array(list(filter((0).__ne__,np.pad(np.array(results), ((0,n*3-l)), mode='constant').reshape((n,3), order='F').flatten())),dtype=object)
```